# Tag rename request: [donkeykong] -> [donkeykong-gb]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[donkeykong](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donkeykong) should be renamed to [donkeykong-gb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donkeykong-gb).

The two questions we have under the tag pertain to the GameBoy version of the game. Donkey Kong is a series of similar games on various different platforms, if the tag is just left as-is it could equally well apply to [dk-country-returns](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dk-country-returns)

We can also leave it as a general place for any of the Donkey Kong games, its not like we have a lot of questions on them - but if so, the tag wiki should be updated to clarify the scope of the tag.

Comment: I didn't even think of that when I asked the questions! I think that this tag change is a good idea. (Although, they're the Game Boy versions, not GBA.)

Comment: @AshleyNunn Thanks for the correction, updated tag suggestion and summary

Comment: @StevenVascellaro, there is no need for an edit like this on a resolved issue from **five years ago**. Superfluous edits like this bump old and irrelevant posts to the front page in place of much more recent issues.

Comment: @Vemonus I realized my mistake as soon as I'd made the edit. I forgot to look at the date before editing...

Comment: Well seeing as it *was* bumped it can have a status-completed tag as well.

Answer (score 3):

This game is known as *Donkey Kong '94* in Europe (and among fans of the game worldwide). If the tag needs to be disambiguated I'd recommend [donkey-kong-94](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donkey-kong-94) instead of [donkey-kong-gb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donkey-kong-gb).

Comment: The tag has been renamed to [tag:donkey-kong-94].